# Unable to extend MapActivity or MapView

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to extend MapActivity in my Activity class but it is not letting me do it. it is asking me "create class MapActivity".

even i am not seeing any Mapview tab in XML layout perspective.
I am developing app on android version 2.2.

Should I need to add something before using MapActivity..

Comment: Did you try organize import (assuming you are using eclipse)?

Comment: do you have `<uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.google.android.maps"></uses-library>` in your manifest?

Comment: yes i did it, I tried cntrl + space to autocomplete, but it do not showing MapActivity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you developing against Android 2.2 with Google APIs? The MapActivity doesn't exist in the vanilla Android 2.2 - you need the Google APIs version.

For example, if we want 1.6 with Google APIs:

[image]

You'll also need this in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```